# style.css not affecting new page template

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have added a new template to my theme folder called login.php.

Here is the code for login.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: login
 * Description: login page
 * @package Backyard Cures
 */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

@import url("./wp-content/themes/backyard-cures/style.css")

<div class="all-content">
<div class="all-content-container">    
    <?php wp_login_form(); ?>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

I am having two problems, perhaps they are related.

1) When I open the login page, the chrome developer does not register the all-content and all-content-container divs.

2)When I try to style the elements in login.php using style.css those changes don't show. In fact, the chrome developer does not seem to be registering any css at all.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`@import` will only work when used within a css file. To include the css on your page you need to do something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./wp-content/themes/backyard-cures/style.css"/>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I tried this already. I had this statement in header.php. I just tried adding it to login.php but to no avail, the styling is still not being applied

Comment: Are the styles using selectors like '.all-content' or '.all-content-container'? Also, are your div's closed?

Comment: Maybe provide a link to the page in question, or provide the css that isn't working.

Comment: yeah, they get closed in footer.php and I am using the proper syntax in my css. In fact, I have the same divs in my home.php and the styling gets applied to those.

Comment: where does login.php get included? if these div's exist in 2 places are they being closed twice? can you inspect the dom and find these 2 div's (not the ones in home.php)?

Comment: I didn't really understand your questions. I have two templates: login.php and home.php, they both call get_header and wp_footer functions. I have the two </div> in footer.php so that no matter what they get closed.

Comment: Oh, login.php is a page then? Do both of the templates exist in the same folder? What differs between the 2 templates?

Comment: I think login.php is officially called a template. I assigned a page to that template and it is the page that is loading. The difference between the two is the content

Comment: Unsure of how to help without being able to see the pages in question (home.php and login.php) and comparing the two.

Comment: One more thing you could check, is the path to your css file the same in the home and the login templates? if both templates are in the same folder, then the path to the css should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Generally `@import` only work when you use it within a css file. To include the css with in your page you need to include it like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./wp-content/themes/backyard-cures/style.css"/>
```

You can read more about `@import` at http://gajjar.me/1tkqiLg

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying your CSS files is not loading? If so, give `bloginfo` a try. This will dynamically create the reference for your template directory.

`<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

It's a handy little WP API
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo

Answer (score 0):

Change your import css to
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/style.css" />`

And don't forget to close you divs 
`</div>`